# How to attach a file to an email in c#

Tags: c#, email, attachment

Hi I believe I am pretty close to figuring out what is wrong with my code, but was hoping someone could help me out or point me in the right direction.  I am able to run my program and on the page where the user is going to be uploading a file it gives me the option to choose a file.  But when I press submit other information gets sent to me but the file never comes.  I think this is because I am having trouble figuring out where to temporarily save the file when it send to my email.  Here is my code at the moment:

Also what this code is for is a comment / request page on my website where the user can comment and also add a screen shot.

```
private string SendMessage(string strTo, string strFrom, string strSubject, string    strMessage, string strAttachment, string strBCC)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mailMsg;
        string strEmail = "";
        string strSmtpClient = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpClient"];
        string[] arrEmailAddress = strTo.Split(';');
        for (int intCtr = 0; intCtr < arrEmailAddress.Length; intCtr++)
        {
            strEmail = "";
            if (arrEmailAddress[intCtr].ToString().Trim() != "")
            {
                strEmail = arrEmailAddress[intCtr].ToString().Trim();
                mailMsg = new MailMessage(strFrom, strEmail, strSubject, strMessage);
                mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                if (!strBCC.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
                    mailMsg.Bcc.Add(strBCC);

                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(strSmtpClient);
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtpClient.Port = 25;

                smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
                mailMsg.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return "Message sent to " + strTo + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".";
    }
    catch (Exception objEx)
    {
        return objEx.Message.ToString();
    }

    string strUpLoadDateTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    string strFileName1 = string.Empty;
    if ((File1.PostedFile != null) && (File1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        string strUploadFileName1 = File1.PostedFile.FileName;
        strFileName1 = strUpLoadDateTime + "." + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strUploadFileName1) + Path.GetExtension(strUploadFileName1);
        strFileName1 = strFileName1.Replace("'", "");
        string strSaveLocation = Server.MapPath("") + "\\" + strFileName1;
        File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(strSaveLocation);
        txtComments.Text = "The file has been uploaded";
    }
```

My question is where am I going wrong where in this code do I put where I want the file to be saved.

The below part of the code is what I am using to format the email when it is sent.  And pick what will be sent in the email.

```
protected void Submit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string dandt = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        string strMessage = "Bug Name: " + txtBugName.Text.Trim() + "<br/>" +
                     "Module Name: " + ddlModule.SelectedValue + "<br/>" +
                     "Page Name: " + ddlPage.SelectedValue + "<br/>" +
                     "Description: " + txtComments.Text.Trim() + "<br/>" +
                      File1.f + "<br/>" +
                      "Email is" + " " + txtemail.Text.Trim() + "<br/>" +
                      "The request was sent at" + dandt;  

        SendMessage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAddrTo"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAddrFrom"],
            txtBugName.Text.Trim(),
            strMessage, "", "");
    }
    catch 
    {
    }
}
```

For some reason now nothing is sending in my emails when I press submit.  Also I was trying to figure out how to put in the email the time and date the email was sent.  Even though obviously my email will have this information, incase the email is delayed for some reason I would like to have the time and date the user pressed the submit button.  Where is says File.F in this part of the code this is where i was trying to figure out how to get the file attachment to go to the email, but I'm not sure what syntax should go there in the code.

Comment: Anyway, use `System.Text.StringBuild` instead of such large string concatenating. It will be faster!

Comment: What part do you suggest I replace that with?

Comment: `System.Text.StringBuilder` - var sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.Add("someText"); blah blah then sb.ToString(); - not really pertinent to the question though and I wouldn't really optimise the code until it works haha :D

Comment: good point Yea I'm going to try to get this working before I try to change (and probably screw up) something else.  Thank you though for the input I appreciate anything and everything

Comment: I cant see where are you using "strAttachment"! It seems to me that you're not using this variable.

Comment: Another shortcut for you: this `!strBCC.Trim().Equals(string.Empty)` can be expressed better by this: `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strBCC)`

Comment: To avoid file name collision, you may want to take a look at these two methods for creating/naming your uploaded files: [System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) and [System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to attach some file from the user's computer to the email you are sending. If that is the case, you need to upload your file first before you call `SendMessage.`

In your `Submit_Click` the first thing you need to do is the code the uploads the file somewhere.  Also, remove that `File1.f` from `strMessage` which is where I suspect is causing your message to null out on you.

After you upload your file, pass `strSavedLocation`, which is the file location you saved the file, to your `SendMessage()` method.

In your `SendMessage` method you can attach the file with the following code where you are buliding your `MailMessage`. `strAttachment` is the path name to your uploaded file:

```
var attachment = new Attachment(strAttachment);
// Add time stamp information for the file.
ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(strAttachment);
disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(strAttachment);
disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(strAttachment);
mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: OK thank you I think I understand Now:  I am such a beginner so thank you for taking your time to help me I put this code together watching lots of tutorials online so i do not fully understand it which is definitely a problem.  Thank you and please check back if you have the time  Edit:  where exactly do I put the code you have given me?  Thank you once again !

Comment: @user1486774, Buck's answer has the code arranged as described here; just replace the three lines starting with `/*** Added mail attachment...` with the code block in my answer. Also, don't forget that you need to call `mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment)` to actually attach the file to your `MailMessage.`

Comment: Thank you so much.  I added in everything you told me too and am getting one last error message.  The contentDisposition is underlined in red and the error message says:  the type or namespace name 'contentdisposition' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  What does this mean? What is it suggesting i need to change?

Comment: @user1486774, It means you are missing a `using` directive at the top of your code. [using System.Net.Mime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition.aspx)

Comment: thanks brad.  Just wanted to say thank you, you are a very good dude If theres some way I can repay you let me know

Comment: @user1486774, glad I can help. No repayment necessary; it's customary to accept the answer if it solved your problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have the major parts here minus the handy, System.Net.Mail.Attachment.

If I were doing this, I'd move the file upload handling code into the Submit_Click handler, and then just add the Mail.Attachment code.

```
    private string SendMessage(string strTo, string strFrom, string strSubject, string strMessage, string strAttachment, string strBCC)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMsg;
            string strEmail = "";
            string strSmtpClient = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpClient"];
            string[] arrEmailAddress = strTo.Split(';');
            for (int intCtr = 0; intCtr < arrEmailAddress.Length; intCtr++)
            {
                strEmail = "";
                if (arrEmailAddress[intCtr].ToString().Trim() != "")
                {
                    strEmail = arrEmailAddress[intCtr].ToString().Trim();
                    mailMsg = new MailMessage(strFrom, strEmail, strSubject, strMessage);
                    mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    if (!strBCC.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
                        mailMsg.Bcc.Add(strBCC);

                    /*** Added mail attachment handling ***/    
                    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(strAttachment);
                    mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(strSmtpClient);
                    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    smtpClient.Port = 25;

                    smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
                    mailMsg.Dispose();
                }
            }
            return "Message sent to " + strTo + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".";
        }
        catch (Exception objEx)
        {
            return objEx.Message.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void Submit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            /*** Moved from SendMessage function ****/
            string strUpLoadDateTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            string strFileName1 = string.Empty;
            if ((File1.PostedFile != null) && (File1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
            {
                string strUploadFileName1 = File1.PostedFile.FileName;
                strFileName1 = strUpLoadDateTime + "." + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strUploadFileName1) + Path.GetExtension(strUploadFileName1);
                strFileName1 = strFileName1.Replace("'", "");
                string strSaveLocation = Server.MapPath("") + "\\" + strFileName1;
                File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(strSaveLocation);
                txtComments.Text = "The file has been uploaded";
            }

            string dandt = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            string strMessage = "Bug Name: " + txtBugName.Text.Trim() + "<br/>" +
                         "Module Name: " + ddlModule.SelectedValue + "<br/>" +
                         "Page Name: " + ddlPage.SelectedValue + "<br/>" +
                         "Description: " + txtComments.Text.Trim() + "<br/>" +
                          strSaveLocation + "<br/>" +
                          "Email is" + " " + txtemail.Text.Trim() + "<br/>" +
                          "The request was sent at" + dandt;


            SendMessage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAddrTo"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAddrFrom"],
                txtBugName.Text.Trim(),
                strMessage, strSaveLocation, "");
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

As for the note about using StringBuilder, I agree, and I would use it like this:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("Bug Name: {0}<br/>", txtBugName.Text.Trim());
sb.AppendFormat("Module Name: {0}<br/>", ddlModule.SelectedValue);
```

Edited To Add:
Also, see Brad's answer above about using ContentDisposition.

Comment: Thank you so much I am very new to coding and put this code together watching many tutorials.  So I know its bad, but I don't even understand exactly what all of my own code does. So adding what you suggested will do exactly what?

Comment: The `new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(strAttachment)` code will create a .NET attachment object with the string path you passed in. `mailMsg.Attachments.Add` will actually attach the file found at the path `strAttachment`.